# A static variable dynamically set during startup of Xamarin Application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have two Apps in Xamarin .One is Android and another is iOS (not in Xamarin.Forms). I want a static variable which indicates if it's iOS or Android (say, 1 for Android and 2 for iOS ) that will be used by entire application. This must be set dynamically because both of these uses same services.It's for distinguishing between the platforms. 
How can i make it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use [DeviceInfo](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/DeviceInfoPlugin) Plugin for this. Nuget Package is [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo).

Use Platform property to get the current Platform of the Device. It will return you an Enum value defining the Platform.

```
var currentPlatform = CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Platform;
```

This will return platform Enum from :

```
public enum Platform
{
    Android,
    iOS,
    WindowsPhone,
    Windows,
    WindowsTablet,
    SurfaceHub,
    Xbox,
    IoT,
    Unknown,
    tvOS,
    watchOS,
    macOS
}
```

You have to install this plugin in all Xamarin Projects you want to fetch the current Platform value. You can assign the result of this property to your static variable to use.

Comment: Does this plugin gives the enum values  only?

Comment: Yes. It will give you only Enum values.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a class with your static variables seems to be what your looking for if your not developing this in Xamarin forms each deployment must be using a different project

So Simply have a class in each of them call it dynamic variables(or what ever else you want )
and set an static integer to the value of 1 on 2 depending on what you want to do then just call that class's variable each time you send something to your service

i have attached a sample

```
namespace MyApp
{
   public class Constants
   {
     public static int DeviceId=  1;//1 for Android 2 for IOS
    }

}
```

then simply call that calls when you reference your service

```
myservice.mymethod(Constants.DeviceId);//sends the deviceid trough the service
```

that should be what you need

Comment: Glad i could help